# Are there any problems outside of the arithmatical hierarchy?

Tags: computability, decidability

Do there exist problems that are outside of any level of the arithmetical hierarchy(as in even outside arbitrarily large ordinal levels?) But are in ALL. In other words, does AH = ALL?(where AH is all of the levels of the arithmetical hierarchy, including all ordinals). If these problems do exist, what are some examples? If there are not problems like this, what is the highest level of the arithmetical hierarchy(the level that is equivalent to ALL) Another way to ask this would be "are there any problems that cannot be computed by a Turing machine with access to a halting oracle for an arbitrary level of AH?"

Comment: "Does god exist" is at the lowest level of the hierarchy, since its answer - either way - is a single bit. Meanwhile, what do you mean by "including ordinals?" There is a way to extend the arithmetical hierarchy through [the computable ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory) or [even further](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183), but this gets increasingly technical.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe i am misunderstanding something? Wouldn't the answer to ANY decision problem just be a single bit? Regardless of it's level in the AH.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. Removed it

Comment: @Colonizor48 "Decision problem" usually refers to an decision problem *with infinitely many instances* - e.g. "which Turing machines halt?"

Comment: (Related: [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84575/turing-degree-incomparable-with-any-countable-ordinal-jump-of-another-turing-deg/92539#92539), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922373/higher-order-busy-beaver-functions-and-the-language-of-first-order-set-theory/2922808#2922808).)

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah i understand. I removed that example as it wasn't a mathmatical question.

Comment: There is a real-world decision problem that known to be non-arithmetical: given an arbitrary legal game state, does the active player in a game of Legacy-format Magic the Gathering have a winning strategy? It is conjectured this problem is actually hyperarithmetical, but this is not proven.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetical hierarchy can be extended to infinite coutable ordinals up to a point : at least you need the ordinal to be [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonrecursive_ordinal), otherwise, you can't define a way for the turing machine to effectively ask a question to the oracle. So you are limited to be under $\omega_1^{CK}$

I don't think it means anything to define the AH for all ordinals (definition problem). So AH up to its limit will only contains a countable number of problems, but the cardinal of all decision problems is $2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: Actually, using [mastercodes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183) you can continue the hierarchy up through $\omega_1^L$, which is consistently uncountable (e.g. if $V=L$). But this is rather technical.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the link, I'll try to read that article !

Comment: Wouldn't the set of ALL decision problems have a higher carnality then the set of real numbers? Because there are more functions R->R then reals. Also are there any problems completely outside of the arithmetical hierarchy, that cannot be reached from any level in it? Even uncountable or inaccessible level of it? If so what is an example of such a problem? If we even have one.

Comment: @Colonizor48 Belatedly, but: a decision problem *by definition* (unless otherwise stated) is limited to questions about natural numbers (or "morally equivalent" objects like finite binary sequences). If you have a broader notion in mind, you should supply it.

Comment: @Noah Schweber  Where would the decision problem "does number k belong to the subset p" where p is a completely random indescribable subset , where would that be on the arithmatical hierarchy?

Comment: @Colonizor48 I'm not sure what "completely random indescribable" means, but presumably it would imply not being in the arithmetical hierarchy at all - everything in the arithmetical hierarchy is, well, arithmetically definable after all.